# Returning an array vs returning int64_t (C/C++)

Tags: c, arrays

Again and again I read that you can't return an array from a function (in C/C++), but if that's the case, how can an `int64_t` be returned from a function? Isn't `int64_t` just an array of `long int`?

(Yes, I know you can return a pointer to the start of an array, but I'm talking about returning `int[4]`, not `int*`.)

Comment: There is no type `int64_t` in C/C++ language standards

Comment: @icepack In C there is, in `stdint.h`; the fixed-width types are optional, though, you won't find `int64_t` in implementations with `CHAR_BIT == 9`.

Comment: @DanielFischer is it part of the standard?

Comment: @icepack, yes, section *7.18 Integer types <stdint.h>*. See page 254.

Comment: @DigitalRoss if you don't mention any standard revision, people assume you are talking about the current revision which is C11 but your section number refers to C99.

Comment: @ouah You wish. If you don't mention the version, there are still people who think you mean C89.

Comment: @icepack And these types are also in the C++11 standard (18.4), again, the fixed-width types are optional, the `(u)int_leastN_t` and `(u)int_fastN_t` are mandatory for `N` in `{8, 16, 32, 64}`, optional for other values of `N`, like in C (99 or 2011).

Comment: Actually, you can return arrays in C++. Stop with the "C/C++" already, it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't int64_t just an array of long int?

No, `int64_t` is an alias to a scalar type (as opposed to an aggregate type like an array type),  and usually it is an alias to `long long` type.

Of course this applies when `int64_t` is defined as exact-width integer types are optional in C.

Comment: Even if it were an array, it would be wrapped in a struct, which makes it copyable.

Comment: @Barmar but in that you'd have to access it like a struct member, with the `.` operator.

Comment: True. I'm thinking of ADTs like the `fd_set` used with `select()`, which are accessed only using API functions and macros, which hide the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually return any type that isn't an array - for example, if you wish to return four int values, you can return a `struct my_4ints { int x[4] };`

But int64_t (on a 32-bit machine) is one 'item'. It happens to be returned as two register values, on x86, typically eax, edx. But that's still returning ONE value.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your array in a struct, you can return it from a function. But it is to be avoided because the ABIs are not completely stable on these kind of thing (example: objects compiled with gcc 3.3 linked to objects compiled with gcc 3.4 on Solaris are not compatible and may crash in that case).